# What is the simplest way to reset array values to 0?

Tags: c, arrays

Assume we have a pointer(e.g., defined as int* p) to the beginning of an array and the size of the array(e.g., 1000). We want to reset all 1000 array values to 0. What is the simplest way?

Comment: @KristerAndersson: make that `1000*sizeof(*p)`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use memset.

```
memset(p, 0, 1000 * sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `memset()` to zero the memory is good for your example of an array of `int`, or for any other integer type.

If the array is dynamically allocated, another option is to allocate it using `calloc()` instead of `malloc()` to guarantee that it is initially set to all bits zero.

For arrays of `float` or `double` (or pointers, if you want them initialised to NULL), using a loop is better, as these methods are not portable: there are no guarantees about the representations of these types, so all-bits-zero does not necessarily represent a floating point zero (although it happens to work for the most common format, IEEE 754) or a NULL pointer (although platforms where this is not the case are rare).

(See [C99](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) §6.2.6 for the guarantees about integer types; and the footnote for `calloc()` in §7.20.3.1.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with:

```
#include <string.h>

memset(p, 0, 1000 * sizeof(p[0]));
```

Comment: It would be better to avoid duplicate answers. Please up vote similar answers instead of duplicating

Comment: My preference is for `sizeof(p[0])` instead of `sizeof(int)` so that the method works even if the type of `p` changes.  I didn't see that in any other posted answers.  I upvoted @MatthewSlattery's detailed answer as well as comments that mentioned this idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want speed, use the standard library function memset.
It essentially just loops through each value and writes a zero, but it's been optimized for speed.

```
void * memset ( void * ptr, int value, size_t num );
```

The prototype is included in `string.h`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bzero, memset, or a plain loop.

Comment: bzero is deprecated. a plain loop should be deprecated :)

Comment: I didn't know bzero was deprecated. Thanks for correcting me. Since when, and why, was it deprecated?